# SQOOP INCR load

Tags: sqoop

For incremental imports based on a date column, how do we extract updated and new records WITHOUT hard-coding  previous date(we cannot hard code previous date every time in production)
For example
Name       Age   update-date
ABC        32    2016-01-01
DEF        22    2016-04-03
GHI        77    2016-02-02

Suppose I loaded first record having date 2016-01-01 using SQOOP in prior  load and now I need to load next 2 records with out hard-coding any date value(2016-01-01) in SQOOP statement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little bit late, but in order to avoid having to introduce the last import value each time, you can make use of the built-in Sqoop metastore and create a [Sqoop job](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_job_literal) in order to do that for you.

For instance, you could use something like this to create a job that checks for new records using the column `dt` of the table `updates`.

```
sqoop job 
   --create update_job 
   --import 
   --connect jdbc:mysql://whatever/database
   --username foo
   --password bar 
   --table updates 
   --incremental lastmodified 
   --check-column dt
```

Once created, you can execute the job and each time it runs, it will import the records starting from the last `dt` recorded from previous imports:

```
sqoop job --exec update_job
```

[Here](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/11436/view.html) you can check a more detailed example.

Comment: Thank you Jaime.This helps.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :-) Please, consider accept the answer if you find it useful and adjusted to what you need.